# プロセス間通信における、ネットワークの必要性について

Tags: python, node.js, raspberry-pi, socket.io

当方、プロセス間通信がよく分かっておりません。

**やりたいこと：**
PythonとNode.js間でのSocket通信において、wifi接続不要な方法を知りたい。

**構成：**
Python: [Flask-SocketIO](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)を用い、サーバとして実装。
Node.js: [bleno](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/bleno)を用い、クライアントとして実装。

いずれも、tmuxの別のペインから独立に実行。

**問題：**
wifi非接続下におけるRaspberryPiにおいて、これらプロセス間の接続が確認できない。

Comment: ２つのマシン（クライアント、サーバ）と、その間にあるネットワークの構成を明らかにしてください。また、「wifi接続不要な方法」がどういう状況で何をしたいのかも説明してください。

Comment: （マシンを、実体のあるハードのことであると解釈しました）同一のマシンのCLIにおいて、tmuxを起動し、複数のペインに切り分けます。別々のペインから実行したプロセス間の通信において、API（インターフェース？なんと呼んでいいのかわかりませんが）としてFlask-SocketIOとblenoを用いています。

Comment: 「どういう状況で何をしたいか」は、wifi非接続条件におけるプロセス間通信です。

Comment: ネットワーク構成とはつまり何を指すものでしょうか？上記の説明で何が不足しているのかお教え願えますか

Comment: １つのマシン(複数のvirtual machinewo

Comment: WiFiがない時でも、ループバックデバイス`lo`はありますから、`127.0.0.1`を使えばいいと思います。